# Why doesn't WebBBS work now that I've migrated to a new server?

Tags: perl, apache, webbbs

I've moved a WebBBS board from one server to another. Ever since the board doesn't work.
I'm getting an Apache error whenever I try to access the board. Don't even know where to start the debugging, I'm not a Perl person. The file paths remained the same and there isn't any DB involved.

http://gammonline.com/members/board/

Any ideas?

After a bit of testing I believe that the problem has something to do with the index.cgi which is located in that folder (not getting the error when renaming it).

Thanks,

Roy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Says it all. You will have to find the error log and look at it.

If you are using CGI, the first step is to check you have given it the right permissions so it is an executable script at all.

```
chmod 755 index.cgi
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by Apache config errors. Set LogLevel debug and tail -f the error log. It will probably be something to do with .htaccess permission for override, or, it's requiring a module which isn't loaded. The error log will tell you instantly.